# TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable while loop through training

Tags: pytorch

I am getting Error: Tensor object is not callable on the following PyTorch code. How to solve this

```py
# Create a linear regression model class
import torch.nn as nn

class LinearRegressionModel(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.weights = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1,
                                            requires_grad = True,
                                            dtype = torch.float))
    self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1,
                                         requires_grad = True,
                                         dtype = torch.float))
  # Forward method to define the computation in the model
  def forward(self, x:torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    return self.weights * x + self.bias # this is the linear regression model
model_0 = LinearRegressionModel()

# Setup a loss function
loss_fn = nn.L1Loss()

# Setup an optimizer
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(params = model_0.parameters(),
                            lr = 0.01) #Stochastic Gradient Descent
epochs = 50

for epoch in range(epochs):
  model_0.train()

  # forward pass
  y_pred = model_0(X_train)

  #calculate loss
  loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y_train)
  #optimizer zero grad
  optimizer.zero_grad()

  #perform backpropagation
  loss.backward()
  optimizer.step()

  model_0.eval()
```

I tried to loop throug the training data and wanted to run the model. But it is throwing error

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-121-1f222417566f> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 epochs = 50
      2 
----> 3 for epoch in range(epochs):
      4   model_0.train()
      5   # forward pass

TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please add your code for model_0, loss_fn. Also add the full traceback

Comment: I have edited my problem. Please have a look now.

Comment: I tried your code with random inputs, it is working, could you restart the kernel and try your code with random inputs: `X_train, y_train = torch.randn(100, 1), torch.randn(100, 1)
`. Also this is the full for loop, right, you are not doing anything after `model_0.eval()`?